# using Function.prototype.bind causes the original properties to be lost

Tags: javascript

```js
function x() { }
x.a = '1'

let y = x.bind({}) // [Function: bound x]
console.log(y.a)
```

function `y` is missing property `a` defined in `x`.

Is there any way I can bind a function's `this` yet still retain its properties like `a`?

Comment: If bind is explicit, why don't you copy properties from x to newly created y?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to achieve it in the way you presented. And to understand why you need to know how the `.bind()` method works.

I think the best explanation can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The bind() function **creates a new bound function**, which is an exotic function object (a term from ECMAScript 2015) **that wraps the original function object**. Calling the bound function generally results in the execution of its wrapped function.

and reading further:

> When a bound function is called, it calls internal method `[[Call]]` on `[[BoundTargetFunction]]`, with following arguments `Call(boundThis, ...args)`. Where `boundThis` is `[[BoundThis]]`, `args` is `[[BoundArguments]]`, followed by the arguments passed by the function call.

That means that in your example, the `y` function is a new function that wraps the `x` function internally and calls it with changed `this` context. The polyfill created on the MDN site I linked explains it perfectly.

`.bind()` returns another function, therefore it does not have any properties you gave it.

---

I don't know your case but one solution for you might be to treat `x` as a constructor function like this:

```js
function x() {
  this.a = '1';
}

const y = x.bind({});
const newy = new y();
console.log(newy.a);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. In my case, I attempt to change a function's bind without affecting its properties. I make it by copying descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like below by copying old function's descriptors to the new one.

```js
const newfunc = func.bind({});
const descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(func);
Object.defineProperties(newfunc, {
  ...descriptors
})
```